# member was already defined

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically im following this tutorial on youtube to make a hack n slash game on unity, and im at this step where i made gave my cube Hp, and the function Attack, to reduce the "enemyCube" hp's. So far so good, but now i need to make the cube Attack me as well, as suggested on the tutorial, the OP creates a new script, called EnemyAttack, and just Copy pastes the PlayerAttack code into it, by just removing the Input.GetKey part, as it wont be needed for the computerAI. It works fine for the OP, but when i try this way, i get the error on the variables used on playerattack, that were copied to enemyattack "member already defined". I know that i can change all the variables names for the enemyAttack, and it would solve the problem, but that does not make sense, what if i had 200 types of enemy, 200 variables that do the same thing, seems wrong. Anyone has idea why i cant just copy paste, and OP can?

Sorry for bad english, i will list the code above.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerAtack : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject target;
    public float attackTimer;
    public float cooldown;
    void Start()
    {
        attackTimer = 0;
        cooldown = 2.0f;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (attackTimer > 0)
        {
            attackTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (attackTimer < 0)
        {
            attackTimer = 0;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
        {
            if (attackTimer == 0)
            {
                Attack();
                attackTimer = cooldown;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Attack()
    {
        Vector3 dir = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
        float direction = Vector3.Dot(dir, transform.forward);
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.transform.position, transform.position);
        if (distance < 2)
        {

            EnemyHealth eh = (EnemyHealth)target.GetComponent("EnemyHealth");
            eh.AddjustCurrentHealth(-10);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any code in there that will give the error, can you specify what line you are seeing this error on?

Comment: Is your question about copy and paste or why you get the error?  EnemyAttack isn't in the code you provided.  There are a lot of formatting issues in your code as well.

Comment: EnemyAttack is a copy of PlayerAttack, thats the problem, when i copy paste the code, it wont let me compile, sayng that  target, attacktimer and cooldown were already defined.

Comment: You haven't changed the name of something, you need to add the "copy/paste" because there is something that is wrong in **that** code that is failing, and we can't see it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any code above your post :)

Comment: _"i get the error on the variables used on playerattack, that were copied to enemyattack "member already defined""_ -- I realize that when dealing with Unity, it's harder to provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. But failing that, it's even more important than usual that you provide the _exact_ details for any error messages you get. Provide the complete text of the error message, indicate _exactly_ which line of code generates the error, etc.

Comment: Assuming your `EnemyAttack` class is really just a copy/paste of `PlayerAttack`, with only the name of the class (and of course of the constructor) being changed, and the class still inheriting `MonoBehavior`, then the error you vaguely describe simply can't happen. We need to see the code that is causing the error (not the code from which you copied the error-causing code), and we need the _specific details_ of the error. Please edit your post to include these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you didnt rename the class in the copy and pasted code.  You can't have two classes that are the same name in the same namespace. Even if the file names are different you still have to change the class declaration to match the file name.